# RESTORE database now in Emergency

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-restore, disaster-recovery

I posted yesterday because we have a database that was basically used for application purposes but it was using "master" - bad indeed. We created a new database called school that is now being used (same structure as how master was minus a table renamed correctly). I was trying to restore a .bak file from the old db (master from sql 2008) to the new school db (school in sql 2016).

Problem is, running the script gave me a bunch of lines saying it's updating, then the restore terminated abnormally... My db was then in a recovery pending state, I tried running emergency code but it seems pretty broken and i'm not sure 1. why it failed in the first place and 2. what to do now.

Below is the script code and the error message

```
use school;

DECLARE @TableSchema sys.sysname = N'dbo'
DECLARE @TableName sys.sysname = N'rolerights'
DECLARE @OldTableName sys.sysname = N'rolerigths'
DECLARE @OldTableWithSchema NVARCHAR(256) = QUOTENAME(@TableSchema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@OldTableName)
DECLARE @TableWithSchema NVARCHAR(256) = QUOTENAME(@TableSchema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @TableSchema
             AND  TABLE_NAME = @TableName))
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_rename @TableWithSchema, @OldTableName
END

DECLARE @Table TABLE ([LogicalName] varchar(128),[PhysicalName] varchar(128), [Type] varchar, [FileGroupName] varchar(128), [Size] varchar(128), 
            [MaxSize] varchar(128), [FileId]varchar(128), [CreateLSN]varchar(128), [DropLSN]varchar(128), [UniqueId]varchar(128), [ReadOnlyLSN]varchar(128), [ReadWriteLSN]varchar(128), 
            [BackupSizeInBytes]varchar(128), [SourceBlockSize]varchar(128), [FileGroupId]varchar(128), [LogGroupGUID]varchar(128), [DifferentialBaseLSN]varchar(128), [DifferentialBaseGUID]varchar(128), 
            [IsReadOnly]varchar(128), [IsPresent]varchar(128), [TDEThumbprint]varchar(128), [SnapshotUrl]varchar(128)
)

DECLARE @Path varchar(1000)='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\SQL2008backup.bak'
DECLARE @LogicalNameData varchar(128),@LogicalNameLog varchar(128)
INSERT INTO @table
EXEC('
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
   FROM DISK=''' +@Path+ '''
   ')

   SET @LogicalNameData=(SELECT LogicalName FROM @Table WHERE Type='D')
   SET @LogicalNameLog=(SELECT LogicalName FROM @Table WHERE Type='L')

SELECT @LogicalNameData, @LogicalNameLog

use master;

declare @MasterData nvarchar(512)
exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\Parameters', N'SqlArg0', @MasterData output
select @MasterData=substring(@MasterData, 3, 255)
select @MasterData=substring(@MasterData, 1, len(@MasterData) - charindex('\', reverse(@MasterData)))
print @MasterData
print @LogicalNameData

declare @MasterLog nvarchar(512)
exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\Parameters', N'SqlArg2', @MasterLog output
select @MasterLog=substring(@MasterLog, 3, 255)
select @MasterLog=substring(@MasterLog, 1, len(@MasterLog) - charindex('\', reverse(@MasterLog)))
print @MasterLog
print @LogicalNameLog

declare @DefaultData nvarchar(512)
select isnull(@DefaultData, CONVERT(nvarchar(512), @MasterData))
declare @DefaultLog nvarchar(512)
select isnull(@DefaultLog, CONVERT(nvarchar(512), @MasterLog)) 

declare @NewDefaultData nvarchar(512) = @MasterData + '\' + 'school.MDF'
declare @NewDefaultLog nvarchar(512) = @MasterLog + '\' + 'school.LDF'

SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY 10
ALTER DATABASE school
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

RESTORE DATABASE school FROM DISK=@Path
WITH MOVE @LogicalNameData TO @NewDefaultData,
    MOVE @LogicalNameLog TO @NewDefaultLog,
    REPLACE

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @TableSchema
             AND  TABLE_NAME = @OldTableName))
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_rename @OldTableWithSchema, @TableName
END
```

And he is the emergency script

```
ALTER DATABASE [school] SET EMERGENCY;
GO
ALTER DATABASE [school] set single_user
GO
DBCC CHECKDB ([school], REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS;
GO
ALTER DATABASE [school] set multi_user
GO
```

And the error:

```
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
Msg 946, Level 14, State 1, Line 5
Cannot open database 'school' version 677. Upgrade the database to the latest version.
Msg 946, Level 14, State 1, Line 7
Cannot open database 'school' version 677. Upgrade the database to the latest version.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
```

Looking at the original logs... this is why it failed. An exception was thrown about filestream garbage collection apparently...

```
FILESTREAM Failed to find the garbage collection table.
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to go into single user mode to restore the master db is to use the -m switch and then restore the master db from SQLCMD. If you want to go into single user mode you probably want to do so using this form:

```
Set Single_User with rollback immediate;
```

Please see this page how to use switches at startup:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/database-engine-service-startup-options?view=sql-server-2017